# How to clear up Datetime and Timezone confusion?

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone, utc

Running a Django web app and settings.py has the following:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

A model's time field is set to `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`.
When I look at the field in the admin screen, it is correct with the UTC timestamp at +8 hours from my local time.

Yet when I display the time on the client, the time is yet another +8 (for a total +16 hours) from my local time.

When I step through the code, there is no change to the date. When the timestamp is queried from the database, it is +8 offset from the actual UTC.

What am I doing wrong? We are running the development environment on Windows and there has been some warning about results being inaccurate. But I've also pushed this to our Linux box and the results are identical.

Comment: I can't remember off the top of my head, but I believe the whole point of Django's `TIME_ZONE` setting is to normalize it _for_ you, which means doing `utcnow()` is doubling the work, hence the double conversion.

Answer (score 1):

In `settings.py`, if

```
USE_TZ = True
```

...then results might not be as expected. I believe there is documentation and I simply missed it. When I removed the setting, the times were being reported as expected.

Provided by [@Two-BitAlchemist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2588818/two-bit-alchemist):

> [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/timezones/) is the relevant documentation. In particular, if you do not have USE_TZ=True, it assumes every date you use is in your local time and converts it to UTC

Comment: [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/timezones/) is the relevant documentation. In particular, if you do not have `USE_TZ=True`, it assumes every date you use is in your local time and converts it to UTC.